Break stuff *without* cellfracture
I'm making a scene where a bullet is shot at a glass object fracturing it completely. cell fracture is great and usually works but it has 2 major flaws. the first is that it sometimes misses fragments in the mesh and you end up with a large gap in your fractured mesh. and the other is that the object appears to be cracked even before impact. The 2nd problem can be easily avoided by keyframing the appearance of shards and the disappearance of intact mesh and it usually passes unnoticed in a quick-paced collision but my scene is slow motion with a high frame rate and I'm trying to make it as realistic as possible so it's not really an option.
If ur lazy read from here:
Is there an addon or a workflow or even a geo node tree that enables me to break objects (glass mainly) realistically where the fragments separate and break gradually and only when collided with?
